# Failed recieving JSON data to ActionScript 3

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash, urlrequest

I am making a program in which I need to download dynamically generated JSON string and then decode and use it in Flash.
When I play swf file, everything goes right, but when I publish it and try to play flash application in .html file it seems like I don't receive any data from server...

```
var urlString:String = "http://test.hfbiz.cz/utils/parc_coord?param=";
var wholeUrlString:String = urlString + wholeString;

// for example: http://test.hfbiz.cz/utils/parc_coord?param=2:764442_2_709_20


var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(wholeUrlString);
var myLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onload);
myLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityError);
myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, IOError);
myLoader.load(myRequest);
...

function onload(evt:Event):void
    {   
        vystup_txt.text = "Data Loaded ";

        var kompletParcelyPole:Array = [];
        var JSONdata:Object = JSON.parse(myLoader.data);
    }
```

Unfortunately I don't even get my tracing note "Data Loaded" when running in browser...
Any ideas what can be done badly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK with your code. I think it is **crossdomain** issue.

[Cross-domain policy errors are always a pain in the ass.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9716418/flash-as3-domain-com-crossdomain-xml-and-security-error)

**Also**: [Crossdomain xml and flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2653398/crossdomain-xml-and-flash)

**And**: [How to use crossdomain.xml for my flash project…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454372/how-to-use-crossdomain-xml-for-my-flash-project/3455045#3455045)

Comment: so the only thing i need is to upload the crossdomain.xml file to the server from which i'am downloading JSON string? am i right?

Comment: I think probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, get a [FlashFirebug](http://www.o-minds.com/products/flashfirebug) for tracing and other debugging you need in browsers.

As for data not being received, I think you're loading data from another domain and you're getting a security error. Try tracing out everything and look at the traces in FlashFirebug.